# Focusrite 3rd-Gen Solo Bundle - Mic Mounted on a Boom Arm Noise Issue

Tags: audio, noise, audio-interfaces

Below is image and voice sample for recording by using Focusrite Scarlett 3rd Gen Solo Studio. Its mounted on a boom arm shock mount. Its got noise. I am touching it then noise goes away but if I withdraw my hand from it, it gives a loud noise. What can be the issue? If I place my hand over audio interface body, then also noise reduces a bit. May be its some sort of interferance noise or ground loop.

https://soundcloud.com/hiroshi-rana/earth

[image]

Comment: Is all your equipment properly earthed?

Comment: how to earth equipment?

Comment: Your Focusrite can pick up an earth from the computer its USB lead is plugged into. Are you using a mains-powered desktop computer or a laptop? Why is your Focusrite on a shock mount? Your microphone can benefit from being on a shock mount but your audio interface doesn't need to be on one. In a previous question about your Boya BY-M1 mic you stated you don't have an XLR mic. Have you got one now because the Focusrite is designed to work with a low impedance balanced XLR mic (and/or an electric guitar/bass)?

Comment: I have purchased Focusrite 3rd-gen bundle. That has got mic, headphone and XLR cable. New audio sample > https://soundcloud.com/hiroshi-rana/focusrite-noise-2

Comment: I got this one https://www.instagram.com/p/CK8_v1rDqcS/

Comment: Touching XLR, some of noise go away. I am using focusrite with laptop / windows 7. Drivers are installed. https://www.instagram.com/p/CK_4WPGDmv5/

Comment: I am sorry, My focusrite is not on shock mount, only its mic is on shock mount.

Comment: laptops are notoriously buzzy. Unplug it & use it on battery only. btw, "how to earth equipment?" would be a good question for google.

Comment: I unplugged everything, moved laptop and only plugged audio interface but still there is noise as shown in this audio. https://soundcloud.com/hiroshi-rana/focusrite-noise-2 
Noise lowers down when I touch XLR cable.